# Limit not working in SQL statement with Variable

Tags: php, mysql

The following statement written in php for a mysql database always brings me the error "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''10'' at line 1'".

```
('SELECT `creator`,`created`,`content` 
FROM mytable 
WHERE `groupid`=? 
ORDER BY `created` DESC 
LIMIT ?', $foo, 10)
```

When I replace the questionmark with a number, it works.

Where is my mistake?

Comment: Bind variables can't be applied to limits, in the same way you can't use bind variables for table names or column names, order direction, etc

Comment: But why? I mean - is there any reason behind this?

Comment: Why? Because of the way bind variables actually work, and what they actually do..... they're not simply a plug-and-play anywhere in a query, but are specific to dynamic arguments used in your WHERE clause

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't bind number to the LIMIT .. just add it to the actual query:

```
('SELECT `creator`,`created`,`content` 
FROM mytable 
WHERE `groupid`=? 
ORDER BY `created` DESC 
LIMIT ' . 10, $foo)
```